# Error says 'configure to use a jdk' though eclipse uses its own compiler. What could be the reason for it?

Tags: java, eclipse, jakarta-ee

The markers window shows this error -

```
Your project must be configured to use a JDK in order to use JSPs.
```

Eclipse by default uses it's own JDK. What could be the problem then ?

Along, I am using *Google App Engine*.

Marker Window -
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Looks like eclipse is configured to use JRE not JDK

verify & change

```
windows > preference > java > installed JRE > choose JDK here
```

Eclipse when started using java from JRE it doesn't still respect this setting, specifying JDK;s java for eclipse fixed it

```
-vm
/home/non-admin/jdk1.7.0_02/bin/java
```

Comment: Why do I put a JDK when it asks for JRE

Comment: may be a bad label there, it needs to set to JDK to use `javac`, also JDK includes JRE

Comment: bad label ! ? But I have known eclipse has its own compiler

Comment: @saplingPro it has its own compiler but that doesn't bring the Java libraries like `java.lang.*` or `java.util.*`.

Comment: eclipse uses `javac` from jdk you set in installed JRE

Comment: @JigarJoshi and where do I set for JRE then ?

Comment: It removed the red mark..but now I get this message `java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot get the System Java Compiler. Please use a JDK, not a JRE.` as I try to deploy to gae. Why is it so ?

Comment: can you tell us how does your installed jre look like now ?

Comment: @JigarJoshi I didn't get you.

Comment: Could you post what path is set exactly for your installed jre now /

Comment: @JigarJoshi you mean the jdk ?

Comment: @JigarJoshi This is path to linked `jdk` _(shown in the snapshot)_ http://s11.postimg.org/5fm3sac37/Screenshot_at_2014_03_14_22_54_03.png

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49771/discussion-between-saplingpro-and-jigar-joshi)

Comment: you have `bin/javac` at that path ?

Answer (score 0):

Go into your 'Project Properties', then go to 'Java Build Path', then to 'Libraries' tab, there you will see 'JRE System Library'. If that doesn't points to the JDK you are using, then 'Edit' it to the correct one.